# Is SQL Server likely to give errors given this usage profile?

Tags: sql-server

I'm developing a web service using asp.net web api 2 which is to be the owner of my SQL Server database.

To simplify things, I'm writing a separate MVC site that is to use the same database, but rather than go through the api, I'm having this site connect directly to the database to manipulate data.

Separately still, I have a contractor who is developing another system which will post data to the api.

With all 3 of these things in use, is SQL Server going to have problems managing connections because so many things will be connecting to the database at once?

Comment: As long as avoid deadlocks - I don't see why it would.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is designed to handle 100's or even 1000's of connections at once. 3 connections will not be a problem.  For security reasons, it is best to use the web service method for all web based connections and only allow the direct connection for connections coming from within the internal network, which includes websites or apps running on the same server.